# Boot kernel parameter to run an executable at the end of booting, if found

Tags: livecd, kernel-parameters

Is there such a feature? The executable would be run if found after the usual boot time mounting. Preferably standard Unix filesystem path; for example, `/root/autorun.sh`, not `(hd0,0)/root/autorun.sh`. This can be useful with live CDs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the kernel would do that. It can't know how and when to start the process, since the boot-time actions like mounting all filesystems are done in userspace, and the kernel can't know when it's done.

But the kernel command line is visible in `/proc/cmdline`, so you could create a tool look for a particular parameter there, and then start the named program. You could then start that tool in some system-level startup script that runs late enough (like `/etc/rc.local`), or in the live user's X startup files if you want to start a graphical program.

In any case, you'll need to create your own live-CD to include that.

Comment: I meant live CDs that I don't have to create. If I create my own live CD I can make it run even two such executables :). By the way, I don't want the **kernel** to do it directly, whatever that means. I just need a boot parameter. I've found parameters that referred to things that assumed mounting plus I totally don't mind it just running the command after a delay or indeed trying again a few times until the first success.